# How to delete all lines in a text file that do not contain the specified words

Tags: python

It is necessary to implement a function in which an array containing several words (the number is unknown) will be passed as a parameter.
There is a source file, output.txt, it contains a large number of lines, it is necessary for the function to delete all the lines entirely if the line does not contain at least one word from the array of words

This is what I have at the moment, but this function only removes one word at a time, but it needs several

```
import re
with open('output.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
str = "bmw" # Keyword
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(str))
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        result = pattern.search(line)
        if result is not None:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: If you want to match multiple words, use a pattern like `word1|word2|word3`

Comment: Okay, but how to cram all this into a loop that will go through an array of words?

Comment: See the linked question.

Comment: You don't need the `result` variable. Just `if pattern.search(line):`

Comment: @Barmar, In a similar question, not exactly what I would like. There is a search for one word in an array of words, but for me it’s the other way around, you need to search for words in a text file in which there are a lot of words (database). I need to delete all lines that do not contain at least one of the words in the array

Comment: The other question is exactly on point. It shows how to match a set of words against a string. You do that when you create `pattern`. Then the rest of your code should work.

Comment: `pattern = '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in list_of_words)`

Comment: BTW, don't use `str` as a variable name. It's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, but could you provide a fully working code for this function, I do not understand anything in this case :(

Comment: Sorry, the question is already closed, answers can't be added.

Comment: Just replace the line `pattern = re.compile(re.escape(str))` with that. `list_of_words` is the list of strings that you want to match instead of the single string `bmw`, e.g. `list_of_strings = ["bmw", "audi", "honda"]`

Comment: Here's what I got - https://i.imgur.com/wFJxlO2, but this code completely deletes all the lines for some reason, and even gives an error

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `re.compile()`. `pattern = re.compile ('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in list_of_words))`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GxvKAnt

Comment: This method removes all - https://imgur.com/a/FULRBdr

Comment: Why do you call `re.compile` twice?

Comment: The statement should just be `pattern = re.compile ('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in list_of_words))`